# Is there a way to enqueue a variable?

Tags: python, variables, queue, enqueue

I've been trying to do it for the past hour but I'm confused about it. This is what I've been trying so far but it doesn't seem to work no matter what I try.

```
def main():
    q = queue.Queue()
    name = input("Enter the person's name: ")
    q.enqueue(name)

main()
```

Comment: What did you expect that to do?

Comment: The method is named `put`, not `enqueue`, and you didn't `import queue`.

Answer (score 1):

The enqueue method in python is called [`put()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.put) that does a `q.enqueue()`. Also make sure you are importing the `Queue` class with an `import queue`.